# How to install GroupPolicy module for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, module, windows-7, group-policy, gpo

I just started writing scripts in PowerShell.
The desired script is supposed to create a local GroupPolicyObject (GPO) which will be specified afterwards. Research showed that it could be done with the `New-GPO` command within the GroupPolicy module for PowerShell. I tried to install the mentioned module but unfortunately nothing I found worked. May I ask for help?

I am using Windows 7 and Powershell 5.1.14409.1005

Error I receive when running example from Microsoft page (`New-GPO -Name TestGPO -Comment "This is a test GPO."`):
[image: Error when running (New-GPO -Name TestGPO -Comment "This is a test GPO.") - example provided by Microsoft]

Comment: On Win7 you need to add `Group Policy Management Tools` under RSAT (check [this blog post](https://newdelhipowershellusergroup.blogspot.com/2012/07/enable-group-policy-powershell-module.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. Install RSAT from Microsoft site:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Step 2.  Enable Group Policy from Windows Features.

Following link describes the steps in details:

https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/05/14/managing-group-policy-with-powershell

Comment: First link is 404.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually extremely simple, but the organization of the modules and features has changed many times in the past ten years, Microsoft Docs don't document the up-to-date way anywhere and all articles found online are very old.

Anyway, to install the Powershell Module called `GroupPolicy`, you need to install the Windows Feature called `GPMC` (Group Policy Management Console) which includes the mentioned module.

```
Install-WindowsFeature GPMC
```

This feature was once a subfeature of the RSAT feature, which is the cause of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools) Group Policy component?

Comment: Yes, I just checked. I did.

Comment: Get-Module -ListAvailable

Comment: It does not appear when running "Get-Module -ListAvailable" but I downloaded it from Microsoft. When trying to reinstall it it just says that it was already installed. I installed (KB958830).